# Python: List pulled from txt file as string not recognised as list

Tags: python, string, list, square-bracket

I saved the show data from the epguide API in a txt file, which looks like this:

[{'epguide_name': 'gooddoctor', 'title': 'The Good Doctor', 'imdb_id': 'tt6470478', 'episodes': 'http://epguides.frecar.no/show/gooddoctor/', 'first_episode': 'http://epguides.frecar.no/show/gooddoctor/first/', 'next_episode': 'http://epguides.frecar.no/show/gooddoctor/next/', 'last_episode': 'http://epguides.frecar.no/show/gooddoctor/last/', 'epguides_url': 'http://www.epguides.com/gooddoctor'}]

When I now try to read it as a list in python it doesn't recognise it as such but only as a string despite the square brackets:

```
    with open(file_shows, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fs:
       fs = fs.read()
       print(type(fs))
       print(next((item for item in list if item['title'] == show), None)['episodes'])
```

Type remains a str and thus the search is also not working. How can I convert the data "back" to a list?

Comment: Anything you read with `fs.read()` is going to come back as a string.  It isn't going to try to parse as a Python expression.

Comment: Thx Tom, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is as follows,

```
with open('fileShows.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fs:
    fs = fs.read()
    print(type(fs))
    my_list = list(fs)
    print(type(my_list))
```

Another is,

```
with open('fileShows.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fs:
    fs = fs.read()
    print(type(fs))
    my_list = eval(fs)
    print(type(my_list))
```

Basically **eval()** converts yours str retrieved from the file pointer to its base type which is of type list.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import json
with open(file_shows, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fs:
       data = json.loads(fs.read().replace("'",'"')) # data will be list and not str
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Hi Gabip, thanks for responding. I tried json.loads(). It gives me the following error: 'TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper' It's weird because type fs is <class 'str'>.

Comment: Updated my solution, please try now :)

Comment: Hi Gabip, you're amazing. Thanks for still trying!! I wrote a quick file again to test your new solution since I'm keen of knowing if it works. Unfortunately now I'm getting this error: 'json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)'. Arpit's eval() solution worked though.

Comment: @dizcotec unfortunately me solution won't work here. I didn't notice that your json elements are quoted with single quotes instead of double quotes and this cause your json to be invalid so `json` module is not able to parse it. If you replace all the single quotes with double with `fs.read().replace("'",'"')` it will work but in your case, I guess using `eval` is better. Anyway, I've update again my solution if you want to try it (I checked it on my machine and it works well).